# remove all lines with nullbytes/corrupt data

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, null

So I recovered a text file from an old hdd, but I failed to completely recover all of the data. The data that wasn't correctly recovered has returned as null bytes. How can I remove every line from the file that contains these bytes?

Example of corrupt data

```
xE3
xAF
xE2
xBF
NUL
xBD
```

and a ton more...

I know NULL is equal to \x00.

How can I remove every line containing corrupt data with sed rather than removing the bytes individually?

There are so many variations of bytes/corrupt data that I doubt I would be able to discover all of them with regex..

Answer (score 2):

To remove lines that contain byte 0 or bytes 128 to 255, you can use:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /[\0\200-\377]/'
```

Or with GNU `grep` built with PCRE support:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -vaP '[\0\200-\377]'
```

See also the `strings` command to extract what looks like printable text from data.

To just remove those bytes:

```
tr -d '\0\200-\377'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this Perl command:

```
<in_file perl -lne's/\0//g; print if $_'
```

`in_file` is the input. Pipe redirection can be used.

It removes NULs globally. You can adjust the regular expression to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all lines of `yourfile` that contain a null byte with gnu sed by

```
sed '/\x0/d' yourfile
```

This also works in a pipe:

```
cat yourfile | sed '/\x0/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `strings` with a minimum length of, say, five characters

```
strings -w -n5 corrupted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it like this:
 `sed -e '/\x00/d' [filename] > [new_filename]`
If you want to edit the file in-place:
 `sed -i '/\x00/d' [filename]`
You can also, combine the two, change the original file and keep a backup copy:
 `sed -i~ '/\x00/d' [filename]`
That will delete any line of the file that contains at least 1 NULL.